# Such + adj. only: Is that acceptable usage? Or should I use "so" only in these cases?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, such

For the word "such", most sources say that it should be followed by a noun (phrase) but mention nothing about "such" + adj.

e.g.

> Such confident of him! But can he pull that off?

> That's such arrogant of him.

I know these sentence wouldn't be considered problematic if I substitute "such" for "so". But can I use "such" as an adverb in this way to modify only an adjective (but not a noun)?

---

[M-W's entry of such as an adverb](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/such#dictionary-entry-3) has the following example:

> such tall buildings

Of course, that can be read as "Such" + "tall buildings" (noun phrase), but can that be also read as "Such tall" (adjective modified by adverb "such") + "buildings"?

---

Related question: [If the rule is "such (a) + adj. + noun", why is "such fun" correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114462/if-the-rule-is-such-a-adj-noun-why-is-such-fun-correct)

This question discussed the sentence "It was such fun for all of us to be together". But I think "fun" in that sentence could be considered a noun. So, in that line of thought, that question does not provide much insight to this question I have.

Comment: _Fun_ is definitely a noun. Treating it as an adjective is a modern, informal usage.

Comment: _So_ before adjectives, _such_ before noun phrases, both of them requiring a _that_ clause to define it. _So tired that I'm going straight to bed; such a long day that I'm skipping supper._

Comment: @JohnLawler, how about sentences like "It has been *so* long since I've met him." or "He is *such* a jerk."?

Comment: Why is this question closed? I've demonstrated research in my question that a) I've suggested that I've found no source commenting on the specific usage of "such" + adj., and b) the closest question on SE (which I've linked) does not provide a relevant answer to this question. Also, responding to the comment above and answer below, they are not direct answers to my question (again, it only comments on "such" + noun, but not the "such" + adj. construct), and I've pointed out counterexamples, suggesting that their statement does not encapsulate all situations.

Comment: @nayfaan _So_ and _such_ are often used alone as emphasizers, like _very_. It's quite informal speech, though, and the _so_ or _such_ often have exaggerated intonations. This phenomenon is often parodied as 'girl talk', though it's not restricted to women.

Answer (score 4):

Is the OP perhaps trying to find a loophole or an exception where "such + adjective" is appropriate and grammatical? I don't know of any exceptions, even when the language is informal and vulgar, *such* does not precede adjectives:

i) *That's **such** [bullshitty](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bullshitty)*  (Nonstandard)
ii) *That's **so** bullshitty*  (Standard)
iii) *That's **such** bullshit*  (Standard)
iv) *That's **such** **a** bullshit(ty) excuse* (Standard)

Person A shows person B an antique photo album. B replies:

iv) They are ***such*** beautiful! (Nonstandard)
v) They are ***such*** beautiful photos! (Standard)
vi) They are ***so*** beautiful photos (Nonstandard)
vii) They are ***so*** beautiful. (Standard)

From Cambridge Dictionary,
<sub>(Apologies for the screenshot because I don't know how to do strikethroughs with the Stack Exchange editor tool)</sub>

> [image: Screenshot of Cambridge Dictionary's article. “Easily confused words > Such or so?”]
>
> **Compare**
>
> | so + adjective | such + noun phrase |
> | --- | --- |
> | you're **so** kind | he's **such a** nice person |
> | it was **so** hot we couldn't work | November was **such** a cold month |

If the OP's own research confirmed that "so + adjective" and "such + noun (or) noun phrase" is considered *standard* English, then they have to accept it.

Comment: Screenshot woks fine. For strikethrough you need <s> to begin it and </s> to finish it :)

Answer (score 2):

> Such + adj. only: Is that acceptable usage?

No. It’s wrong. It sounds awful.

> Or should I use "so" only in these cases?

Yes, that is a good idea.

> most sources say that it should be followed by a noun (phrase)

Those sources are correct.

> This question discussed the sentence "It was such fun for all of us to be together". But I think "fun" in that sentence could be considered a noun.

Fun **is** a noun in that sentence.

> So, in that line of thought, that question does not provide much insight to this question I have.

It **does** provide insight – it agrees with

> most sources say that it should be followed by a noun (phrase)

And that quote should be "**all reliable** sources, **in which the following word or words are referenced**, say that it should be followed by a noun (phrase).

Answer (score 1):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> *So* before adjectives, *such* before noun phrases, both of them requiring a *that* clause to define it. *So tired that I'm going straight to bed; such a long day that I'm skipping supper.*

Comment: Adjectives or adverbs, of course.